# Scala type inference for both a generic type and it's type parameter - why doesn't it work?

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference, type-parameter, higher-kinded-types

If I were to name the single most annoying thing about scala, it would be that for the following code:

```
trait G[+T]
class H[+T] extends G[T]

def f[A<:G[X], X<:Int](g :A)

val g :H[Int]
f(g)
```

the compiler infers types of the last call to f[H[Int], Nothing] and complains before me for its own stupidity.

Knowing scala however, it actually knows better than me. What's the reason behind it? As both G and H are covariant regarding to T, `S <: G[X] with H[_] <=> S<: H[X]` for any type S. This one shortcoming made me design everything around avoiding having to specify the types explicitly - it may look like nothing here, but when names become of 'real' length and pretty much any method is generic, and often working on two generic types, it turns out that most of the code are type declarations.

EDIT:
the case above was solved below by Noah, but what when derived class is not of the same kind as the base class, as below?

```
trait G[+X]
class H[+X, Y] extends G[X]
class F extends G[Int]
def f[A<:G[X], X<:Int](g :A) = g

val h: H[Int, String] = ???
val g :F = ???
f(g)
f(h)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make `A` take a type paramater `A[_]` I think you can get the Scala compiler to agree with you instead of just making everything `Nothing`:

```
def f[A[_] <: G[_], X <: Int](g: A[X])
```

As a side note, I usually take a look in the [`scalaz`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) source whenever I have a type problem as they have usually encountered it and solved it as best as possible.

**UPDATE**

The method I provided above still works with the additional constraints given:

```
  trait G[+X]

  class H[+X, Y] extends G[X]

  class F extends G[Int]

  class I extends G[String]

  def f[A[_] <: G[_], X <: Int](g: A[X]) = g

  val h: H[Int, String] = new H[Int, String]
  val g: F = new F
  val i:I = new I
  f(g) //works
  f(h) //works
  f(i) // should fail and does fail
```

Comment: Thanks, its certainly helpful and looks like it circumvenes the problem here. It won't help however if H is of a different kind - takes more type parameters or none, instantiating G's parameter. Or if H introduces bounds on its parameter. So I'm still interested if there is a reason why the above doesn't work.

Comment: You'll have to give another example of what doesn't work, I'm pretty sure that you can usually get the compiler to agree with you. What's happening in the above is that compiler is having trouble extracting the type from `g:A`. It can figure out that `A` is `H[Int]` but you don't specify `X` so it barfs even though you say `A <: G[X]`. In the example I gave, the type `X` is specified so the compiler can infer it.

Comment: @Turin the method I provided works for the new cases you added

Comment: Wow, thanks! I guess a large refactor awaits me at some point, I'll see if it solves all my practical issues.